# what is the error in my code of CSES problem static range sum query

Tags: java, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve this problem   https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1646. Why am I getting Runtime error an array of up to 200000 elements? Where am I wrong. I used a sparse Table to solve that problem.

`static  long st[][] = new long[100000][k+1]`
what should be the size of 2d array `st[][]`.

My Code:

```
class Mai{

    static int n;
    static int k=17;
    static  long st[][] = new long[100000][k+1];
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
        Reader sc = new Reader();
        int n =sc.nextInt();
        long q =sc.nextLong();
        long a[] = new long[10000000];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            st[i][0]=a[i];
        }
   
        for(int j=1;j<k;j++){
            for(int i=0;i+(1<<j)<=n;i++){
                st[i][j] = st[i][j-1] + st[i + (1 << (j - 1))][j - 1];
            }
        }
        while(q-->0){
            int l= sc.nextInt();
            int r =sc.nextInt();
            l--;
            r--;
            query(l,r);
        }
    }

    public static void query(int l,int r){
        long sum=0;
        for(int j=k;j>=0;j--){
            if((1<<j)<=(r-l+1)){
                sum+=st[l][j];
                l+=1<<j;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
     }  
}
```

And the error I'm getting is shown in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zlKi.png)

Comment: what is the need of the error message image, can't you copy/paste/type the error message, I can't search images for similar errors

Comment: the trick of the question is to use `Cumulative Sum`, then each query is just subtraction of 2 array elements, don't do side effects (printing) in the calculation function

Answer (score 0):

look look at here, you may get some help..
We will use a 2-dimensional array for storing the answers to the precomputed queries. st[i][j] will store the answer for the range [i,i+2j−1] of length 2j. The size of the 2-dimensional array will be MAXN×(K+1), where MAXN is the biggest possible array length. K has to satisfy K≥⌊log2MAXN⌋, because 2⌊log2MAXN⌋ is the biggest power of two range, that we have to support. For arrays with reasonable length (≤107 elements), K=25 is a good value.

Comment: But I want wanted to know the exact numeric value of biggest possible array length.